# Implement P2P file transfer using NS2/NS3

Tags: python, c++, tcl, ns2, ns-3

I am working on a peer-to-peer file transfer project that should be implemented either using NS2 or NS3.

It would be of great help if anyone could give some pointers or source codes using which I can work on.

Note: A simple P2P file transfer code would also be very helpful, in which the peer nodes maintain a database of nodes that contain the files.

Answer (score 0):

**ns3 p2p** https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns3+p2p

ns3 example  https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/nms-p2p-nix_8cc.html

ns3 Forum https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

ns3 p2p INFO  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-3-users/p2p|sort:date

.....

**ns2** **Zetasim p2p** 
https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+zetasim

Zetasim code http://code.google.com/p/zetasim/

p2p-Zetasim_ns234.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZnhnYXBlb2tOeEk/view?usp=sharing

p2p-ZetaSim_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNMmM4RVd4eGFxT2M/view?usp=sharing

....

**ns2** **bittorrent-p2p** : p2p-bittorrent.tar.gz → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNaGhxNEIteC11YTg/view?usp=sharing

p2p-bittorrent_ns234.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWXoyTzJ3Q05WdTg/view?usp=sharing

p2p-bittorrent_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNMi16cmtFdXhJdjA/view?usp=sharing

....

**p2p INFO ns2** http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/p2p-ns2/

. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/bittorrent-p2p/

. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/p2p|sort:date

.....